# Thread to handle Large List of objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a very large `ArrayList` of object, it executes smoothly in a single thread. but execution time is the factor.

Let my list has 50 elements, and I have 3 threads,

I would like 1st thread will process 0 to 15 and 2nd thread will process 16 to 31 and rest of the process will process by the third thread.

Is it possible?

Comment: *"Is it possible?*" Yes.  Personally though, I'd use an [Exectuor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) service of some kind, maybe a [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).  This way, the executor can process the list based on the availability of the items in the list...for example...

Comment: of course its possible, but what are you trying to achieve by having 3 threads run together, total runtime would be higher than using 1 thread

Comment: @PulkitSethi: Why? Depending on the work being done (of which we have been told nothing), it could be up to three times faster. Of course, it could also be slower... Depends entirely on the type of workload and available resources (CPU, IO, memory etc).

Comment: Have you looked at the `ArrayBlockingQueue` class?

Comment: processing 50 objects in single thread should be faster than having 3 threads process part of list cos of switching

Comment: @PulkitSethi - I don't think that is true.

Comment: @PulkitSethi - Sometimes.  Sometimes not.  It really depends what the processing is.  And your resources.

Comment: Its definitely true unless you have true multi core processing, assuming the processing is same on all items

Comment: @PulkitSethi It is not necessary true even without multi-core.  For example, if the "processing" is using most of its time waiting for IO, it will still be faster if you have several threads on 1 CPU core.

Comment: @PulkitSethi - most modern PCs are multi-cored.  Single-core systems are the exception these days.

Comment: @PulkitSethi - there are not 50 element there are thousands of object, I use 50 as exampl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you case, optimal is to use one thread reading urls from excel file and putting it in an ArrayBlockingQueue with limited capacity. Start several working threads which take urls one by one and scrape the referenced site. Standard thread pool would not help, as each piece of work needs blocking while accessing site, and thread pools do not like when their threads are blocked. The only parameter which needs tweaking is the number of working threads. Try 10, 100, 1000, 10000 to find out the fastest configuration. If for several thousands of threads, memory is exhausted but the optimum is not reached, then switch to some NIO library like Netty.

Answer (score 3):

It is technically possible to do that, but it is not a good idea:

- Any fixed partitioning has a risk that the worker thread workloads will be unbalanced.  The time taken to finish the parallel part of the computation is the maximum of the times of each of the worker threads.
- The `ArrayList` could become a contention bottleneck, especially if the threads need to update it.

A better approach is to use a queuing mechanism with the workers all taking work from the same queue.  And a simple way to implement this is to use an `ExecutorService` with a bounded worker pool.  (The fork-join framework is another possibility, though that is more suited to dynamic or recursive tasks where there are dependencies between the tasks.)

Comment: Let me clear the details, I read thousands of url from excel and save it in a arraylist, and then I am to scrape for each of the url from certain site. I use Arraylist so that I can excess any element based on index.